# Pascal Runtime Error 106 on Homework

Tags: pascal

First time posting here so I will try to do it right.

I'm working on my first program which prints the percentages for a class of students given an id,last & first name, and an assignment score which must be converted. I was able to compile it with only two warnings about assignment_score and assignment_percentage being uninitialized.

I'm getting runtime error 106 (which is when a nonnumeric value is read where a numeric value is expected) in my read_record, initialize, and main modules (I think that's the term).

It has to do with the spacing in the data file, but maybe I did something wrong in the code, as this is my first program I am looking for any help possible.

Read_Record :

```
begin
  if EoF(FileIn) then
    more_students := False
  else
    readln(FileIn,student_id,last_name,first_name,assignment_score)
end; {read_record}
```

Initialize:

```
Procedure initialize;
begin
  more_students:= True;

  {Assigns files to input and output and rewrites them for the code }
  Assign(FileIn, 'prg2a-150.dat');
  Reset(FileIn);
  Assign(Fileout, 'Prog2.txt');
  Rewrite(fileout);

  READ_RECORD;
  Print_Header
end; { initialize }
```

My process & main (I get an error at line 100 when I call for process to be used which is where I'm writing my FileOut)

```
procedure process;
begin
  {Line check for print header}

  if line_count > 57 then
    print_header;

  Inc(line_count);

  { Converts score to percentage }
  compute_grade;

  {Report Percentage}
  writeln(FileOut, student_id, space(2), last_name, space(1), first_name, space(2), assignment_percentage:5:1);

  { Next Runner Data }
  read_record
end; { process }


{WRAP UP -- No summary so  just the files are being closed }
procedure wrapup;
begin
  close(FileOut);
  close(FileIn)
end; { wrapup }

begin { main }
  initialize;

  while more_students do
    process;

  wrapup
end.
```

And finally, here is my data file:

```
032919631 BACH                AMANDA    14.1 

327777582 GUNDERSON           EMILY      9.9 

188941863 DARLING             CHRIS     14.7 

396501493 JACKSON             GUY        2.1 

552753315 MILKOVICH           LAURA 21.0 

553962171 ZADINS              WALLACE   28.9 

989570643 KLIPP               JOAN      33.3 

468497243 CARPENTER           BETTYANNE 6.0 

112324230 RIKER               NANCY     17.1 

720789066 UTHE               SHARON    12.7 

878468839 NULL                LIVAK      0.0 

606537736 ZUCKERMAN           YVONNE     1.0 

996498720 KINGSLIGHT         JERRIE    14.5 

453310627 GAUTHIER            DONALD     7.8 

289324008 HIRSH               GAYLENE   32.3 

361582495 KELLY               JEAN 0.1 

441892834 FACTOR              DANI      15.8 

255715006 MARKS               KIMBERLEE 8.9 

535282507 MORROW              LEONARD   29.8 

566318464 COSGROVE            CAROL     15.8 

158778873 MUDD                LES  29.1 

574450163 TIMMERMAN           ROY        2.9 

032731233 MUIZNIECE           LESLIE    14.3 

832142931 HARMAN              FRITZ     34.5
```

Comment: Which exactly is your "line 100" where you get the error?

Comment: line 99: while more_students do

line 100: process;

Comment: Does it happen on the first iteration or the last? Why not turn on debugging and step through the procedures?

Comment: You said: *First time posting here so I will try to do it right.* You have started pretty good, but still, please, visit following links: [**The Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow. Also [**What should I do when someone answers my question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Here's one more link to the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

If your input file really has an empty line between every two data lines, ReadLn will throw an error as soon as it reads an empty line, because you told it to expect a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

> The following WILL help. DO NOT
> *READ into a INTEGER variable a STRING.
>
> ```
>   *HERE is an example output/error :-
> ```

```
   *--S P A C E --
    ? kk
    Runtime error 106 at $0804893A
      $0804893A
      $0806D76D*
```

> CORRECTED

```
*--S P A C E --
? 1
...
...
EXIT*
```

> ```
> *Above NOT *kk* BUT *1*
> ```